# How to grab images from folder and post direct links using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gif

Quick question: I'm trying to create a chrome extension that has gifs, I would like to grab those gifs from a folder on my server. How can I grab gifs from that folder and post them as gifs dynamically?

Comment: Dynamically? Using what? Why is it marked as google-chrome-extension? Please elaborate.

Comment: I'm building a google chrome extension, you can only use HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I need to grab images from a folder on a server using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic HTML :

```
<img id="dynamic" src="" alt=""/>
```

JavaScript :

```
document.getElementById('dynamic').src = '/image/path.gif';
```

Jquery :

```
$('#dynamic').attr('src', '/image/path.gif');
```